# Google Apps Script custom function stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have very simple script (custom function)
'''

```
/**
 * Return order amount in words.
 *
 * @param {amount} is order amount
 * @param {currency} is order currency: BYN, RUB, EURO
 * @return The order amount in words.
 * @customfunction
 */

function orderAmountInWords(amount, currency) {
  return AmountInWords.FloatToSamplesInWordsRus(amount, currency);
}
'''
```

Until yesterday everything was working fine
But yesterday something broke

I see "Loadding..." and a tip "Error loading data" in the place where the result of the function should be

The only guess as to the cause is that I was trying to restore a previous version of the spreadsheet.
The function from the library works fine in other spreadsheet and in debug mode.
I deleted the restored versions, removed the script and created it again, but nothing changed
It looks like the link between spreadsheet and script is lost, but autocomplete works

Maybe I should copy all the data to a new spreadsheet, but that spreadsheet is connected to appsheet application so I don't like the idea of making changes in another app.

Comment: `AmountInWords.FloatToSamplesInWordsRus()` must be coming from a library.  Have you added the library as a resouce in script editor?  On the left under Library +.

Comment: Of course, I added
 No problems with Library

Comment: There seems to be an issue with custom functions today.  See this article https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/SR46fIb3OTU  or this https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/D9rPBvOr5L0  or this https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/IuBHIZ4QBWw

Comment: Today another very strange situation happened: I opened this spreadsheet from another computer, but I logged in through the same account and chrome browser. And everything worked. I returned to my home - and again I see the same picture: "Loading..."

Comment: The same library works fine in another spreadsheet

Comment: It seems that there are several people having the same problem, you may want to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340032/custom-functions-intermittently-hang-with-error-loading-data)

Comment: Started working for me today

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom functions intermittently hang with "Error - Loading Data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340032/custom-functions-intermittently-hang-with-error-loading-data)