# Google Sheets App Script - Error Loading Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am doing my first steps in AppScript for Spreadhseets. My problem is that sometimes these functions work properly, sometimes when I open the sheet it is saying Loading like in the image below.

[image]

What I have done to create these functions? I have created 3 functions in the online script editor and hit the Save button and that is it. I see there some Deploy button, but I don't know what it is and it looks like it is not necessary to Deploy - Saving is enough.

[image]

Have I done something wrong? Why my scripts don't work consistently? And why functions defined by me don't appear in autocomplete when I wrote in a cell `=MY_` like other Sheet functions?

Comment: Looks like this is a bug? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097?pli=1

Comment: Similar or same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340032/custom-functions-intermittently-hang-with-error-loading-data

Comment: Yeah  the "error loading data" is something that I've encountered on an intermittent basis too. Don't have any specific solutions for that — sorry. As for the autocomplete, you'll need to add a JsDoc-styled tag as described here — https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#autocomplete

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: @SourabhChoraria thanks for the JsDoc-styled tag link.