# IMPORTHTML in GoogleSheet Stuck on Loading

Tags: google-sheets

I've an html page on my own server which contains a table. Everything was working fine. Since today's morning i am getting following error message on Chrome console.

```
This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.
```

Any solution, how to authorised IMPORTHTML Script in GoogleSheet.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet? In any case, this is most likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71340032

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue with Google Sheets and is not a symptom of an incorrect formula or a mistake on your part.

https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/t5blgz/is_importxml_broken_was_working_for_months/
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/163269/importhtml-stuck-on-loading
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/153166088

The Sheets development team is already aware of the issue, so I guess all we can do is be patient.
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/153637852

> Update (March 5th): we are actively investigating and fixing the issue. In early next week (the week of March 7th), we are expecting to release a fix. Again, our sincere apology on the inconvenience.